# Locate specific word in string and print rest of line

Tags: c#, string

I have a string in which I want to locate a specific word, and then print the rest of the line containing that word.

String example:

```
    NumberofCars: 12
    NumberofBikes: 3
    NumberofShoes: 6
```

So say I want to know what comes after NumberofBikes in the string, but not anything else (ie. NumberofShoes). The console should just print "3".

Code example of what I want to have:

```
    if string.Contains("NumberofBikes")
    {
      Console.Writeline(Rest of that line);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Start with some code. It is not clear what are going to get.

Comment: Please add a tag with or describe your programming language.

Comment: use regex? or split on the line breaks and parse each line? or...?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Regex` for that. Search for your words followed by a capturing group of digits (assuming you will always have digits that you want to capture). The capturing group allows you to get the value back. Here is a sample code:

```
// The original string to search within.
string s = "NumberofCars: 12\r\nNumberofBikes: 3\r\nNumberofShoes: 6";
// The search value.
string search = "NumberofBikes";
// Define a regular expression for executing the search.
Regex rgx = new Regex(search + @".*?(\d+?)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
// Find matches.
MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(s);
if (matches.Count > 0 && matches[0].Groups.Count > 1) //At least one match was found and has a capturing group.
{
    Console.WriteLine(matches[0].Groups[1]); //Return the first capturing group of the first match.
}
```

You can see a [demo here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OYcUMB)